# fvisibility=hidden but full specialized function is not hidden

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, clang, linkage

I have compiled a `.hpp` and `.cpp` file with the compiler flag`-fvisibility=hidden` with GCC/Clang
and the strange thing is that nevertheless I declared `-fvisibility=hidden`, the following function which is nowhere used in my entire library shows up in my shared object file:

Function in `A.hpp`

```
double f();
template<typename T> T functionT();
```

Function in `A.cpp`

```
double f(){ /* some definition */ }   
template<> double functionT<double>(){ return f(); }
```

However if I declare the full specialized `functionT` as `inline` and move it to the header file, it is no more visible in the shared object file `.so`.

Does somebody know, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not marked as a 'weak' symbol?

Comment: it was marked T in in the output of the nm command

Comment: You should: show us the whole code (compilable source code and how you compile it) and output from nm

Comment: jep i think i should do that, will add this in a while